# MySQL: Split string SQL to be used in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

I am looking for a way to use the IN keyword in JasperReport. My query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CID IN (145,45, 452);
```

following that in jasper report I can setup this;

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CID IN ($P{MY_CIDS});
```

and from my Java I would send `$P{MY_CIDS}` as a `String`, so my query will look like

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CID IN ("145,45, 452");
```

My questions is how to transform in SQL `"145,45, 452"`  to a valid query so it would take into consideration each value separately `145`, `45`, `452`

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(CID, "145,45,452")
```

But this query will always cause table fullscan. So I suggest you to rewrite your code and use proper `IN (A, B, C)` syntax.

Comment: nice solution it is working this way. I dont mind about the  fullscan at this time as this report is only generated twice a year.

Answer (score 1):

You've two options.  The more common, is to rewrite your query like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CID IN (?, ?, ?, ..., ?);
```

I'm not sure the other is valid for MySQL, but it works fine in PostgreSQL. It is to use an immutable function that parses the string into a set of integers, and instead use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CID IN (split_to_int(?));
```

Comment: thanx @Denis, unfortunately there is no split_to_int in MySQL.

Comment: @Adnan: I'd say *fortunately* there is no such function ;-) Otherwise no one will ever care of normalized db schemas ;-)

Comment: @Adnan: by that, I was meaning you'd write that function yourself if it's possible to write set returning functions in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CID IN ($P!{MY_CIDS});
```

Just use

```
$P!{MY_CIDS}
```

(**exclamation mark** between $P and {MY_CIDS}).

Jasper will now concatinate the Strings like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CID IN ("
+"145,45,452"
+")";
```

resulting in:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CID IN (145,45,452);
```

Took me a long time to get that but now it works for me."